# LSTM Vanishing Gradients

Tags: lstm

I'm trying to implement the LSTM model for text classification where each sentence is about 1500 words. converted sentence to a sequence of values and fed to LSTM but gradients are becoming zero. I'm unable to fix it. why LSTM is facing a vanishing gradients problem.

input is {text,label}\n
where text1= "the length of sentences is 1200 words" and label is 0 \n
text2= "the length of sentences is 1500 words" and label is 1\n

Model is

```
class classifier(nn.Module):

#define all the layers used in model
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, n_layers,bidirectional, dropout):
    
    #Constructor
    super().__init__()          

    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, 
                       hidden_dim, 
                       num_layers=n_layers, 
                       bidirectional=bidirectional, 
                       dropout=dropout,
                       batch_first=True)
    
    self.act1=nn.ReLU()
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2 , output_dim)
    self.act2 = nn.LogSoftmax(1)
    
def forward(self, text, text_lengths):
    embedded = self.embedding(text)
    #embedded = [batch size, sent_len, emb dim]
    packed_embedded = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths.cpu(),batch_first=True)
    
    packed_output, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(packed_embedded)
    print("packed",packed_output)

    hidden = torch.cat((hidden[-2,:,:], hidden[-1,:,:]), dim = 1)
            
    #hidden = [batch size, hid dim * num directions]
    outputs1=self.act1(hidden)
    dense_outputs1=self.fc(outputs1)

    outputs=self.act2(dense_outputs1)
    
    return outputs
```

output_dim considered is 1 to do binary classification

I tried reducing the length of sentences to 200 words but still vanishing gradients problem is arising.

Any reference is appreciable

Comment: This code doesn't actually implement a model because we don't know which attributes of `self` intake what data and in what order.

Comment: I think at least now the question contains a complete model. Please try to remove closed since I'm searching from the last 3 days, any kind of reference might be helpful

Comment: You appear to be asking us to debug your code -- without even offering information about the input!  If you could include a minimal reproducible example this question might work on [SO].